# Disallow starring / pinning of messages that are too old / are in rooms you aren't in

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

Currently one can star / pin messages, even those which are off the transcript board, extremely old, or are in another room (including frozen ones)

This is possibly a bug, where such messages can be pinned and reappear on the transcript board for two weeks. Here's a demonstration (for science):

#### Java Transcripts, before surprise pin:

[image]

#### Meanwhile, two years ago...

[image]

With a simple `POST` request to pin...

[image]

It appears!

[image]

Please impose a restriction not to allow such messages to be starred / pinned.

Comment: Not sure it's worth spending time on. Is there real harm in this? Only room owners/mods can do it.

Comment: You're breaking the system. If you were doing this the 'conventional' way, the chat-master.js would stop you and tell you something along the lines of: 'this message is too far back'

Comment: Noooooo, you have broken chat!

Comment: Too much blue in the first screenshot...ohh my eyes!!

Comment: I disagree with this. Sometimes I *want* to star or pin a message from a long time ago.

Comment: @hichris Example?...